# Are these the correct bounds of the limit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to verify that $$w(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\iint_Df(y,\tau)dyd\tau$$ is the solution of the problem $$w_{tt}=c^2w_{xx}+f(x,t) , \ \ x>0, t>0 \\ w(x,0)=w_t(x,0)=0, \ \ x>0 \\ w(0,t)=0 , \ \ t\geq 0$$

where $D$ is the following set: [image]

$$$$

Do we have the following bounds at the limits? $$w(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t\int_{c(t-\tau)-x}^{x+c(t-\tau)}f(y,\tau)dyd\tau$$ Or how is $D$ defined?

Comment: This is [Duhamel's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle#Wave_equation)

Comment: $D$ is just the grey part. So is the lower bound for $x$ not $ct-x$ but $x-ct$ as in the link? @Dylan

Comment: You're right. It's related, but not the same, due to the boundary condition at $x=0$

Comment: So, are the bounds that I used correct? Or is the lower bound that I used correct? I am not really sure because I have calculated the partial derivatives of $w$ and as it is now the problem is not satisfied. So either the bounds are wrong or I have a mistake at the calculations of the derivatives. @Dylan

Comment: Your bounds are incorrect. You should split the integral into to parts: one for $0 < \tau < t-x/c$ and one for $t-x/c < \tau < t$. The first one has the same bounds you wrote, but the second one has a different lower bound.

Comment: So, do we you mean that we have the function $$w(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^{t-\frac{x}{c}}\int_{c(t-\tau)-x}^{x+c(t-\tau)}f(y,\tau)dyd\tau+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{t-\frac{x}{c}}^t\int_{c(t-\tau)-x}^{x+c(t-\tau)}f(y,\tau)dyd\tau$$ ? @Dylan

Comment: No.The lower $y$ bound for the second term should be $x - c(t-\tau)$. See the graph.

Comment: Ahh so $$w(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^{t-\frac{x}{c}}\int_{c(t-\tau)-x}^{x+c(t-\tau)}f(y,\tau)dyd\tau+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{t-\frac{x}{c}}^t\int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)}f(y,\tau)dyd\tau$$ right? @Dylan